# Regex for finding a sequence

Tags: python, regex

I have a string consisting of Latin letters and I need an regular expression that will find a sequence that does not contain [ABC][ABC]. For example, I have the string "AGSHDGSGBCHAHSNABHJDKOCA" and all matches will be "AGSHDGSGB", "CHAHSNA", "BHJDKOC", "A"

I tried using `(?!.*[ABC][ABC]).+` but when i used the code

```
pattern = r'(?!.*[ABC][ABC]).+)'
text = 'AGSHDGSGBCHAHSNABHJDKOCA'
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(matches)
```

it only outputted `['A']`, but I would like the output to be`"AGSHDGSGB", "CHAHSNA", "BHJDKOC", "A"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split with regex `(?<=[ABC])(?=[ABC])`. It will split text exactly like you want.

```py
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[ABC])(?=[ABC])','AGSHDGSGBCHAHSNABHJDKOCA')
# ['AGSHDGSGB', 'CHAHSNA', 'BHJDKOC', 'A']
```

This regex matches transition between one letter of set {`A`,`B`,`C`} and another, using lookbehind and lookahead.

**EDIT:**
For cases when matching empty pattern is prohibited you can also use `findall` with pattern `.*?(?:[ABC](?=[ABC]|$)|$)`.

```py
>>> re.findall(r'.*?(?:[ABC](?=[ABC]|$)|$)', 'AGSHDGSGBCHAHSNABHJDKOCA')
# ['AGSHDGSGB', 'CHAHSNA', 'BHJDKOC', 'A']
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/UdfipE/1).

Comment: ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.

Comment: If you're using 3.6 it looks like there was [a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue43222) there.

Comment: By the way, I tried using `re.sub()`, replacing the pattern '`(?<=[ABC])(?=[ABC])'` with a `' '` and then just using the `string.split()` method and it worked.

Comment: @ganspuzzles, your code will work if it's guarantied that input doesn't have spaces. Just use second approach from my answer, it will be safer (and works in one command instead of two).